# Running window.onload and setTimeout do not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 scripts.
The first script runs as soon as the page loads and lasts 1.5 seconds.
The second script should run afterwards. However, nothing happens.
This is the 2nd script which uses 'setTimeout.'

```js
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout = (changing,2000);
}


function changing() {
    let myImgS = document.querySelectorAll('.linkImgI');
    for(let myImg of myImgS) {
        myImg.className = 'linkImgF';
    }
}
```

```css
.linkImgI {
 transform: scaleY(0.001);
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
 transition: transform 2s;
}
.linkImgF {
 transform: scaleY(1);
 transform-origin: 0% 0%;
 transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <div class='link'><img class='linkImgI' src='her.jpg' alt='test'></div>
 </body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Hello_world_example

Comment: Consider introducing yourself to the browser's debugger. As a reward, it'll tell you about the current value of any variables (which are in scope at the time of examination). It will also let you single-step through your code. Ctrl-Shift-I will start the process. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an object to a variable instead of calling a function. Instead, use:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(changing, 2000);
}


function changing() {
  let myImgS = document.querySelectorAll('.linkImgI');
  for (let myImg of myImgS) {
    myImg.className = 'linkImgF';
  }
}
```

```css
.linkImgI {
  transform: scaleY(0.001);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.linkImgF {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='link'><img class='linkImgI' src='her.jpg' alt='test'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Leo_p You have to wait 2 seconds. Then it will show an image.

Comment: What I mean is that the code you give as a correction to my code is, in fact, my code with any corrections or variations. It is my code which is not working.

Comment: @Leo_p Have you read the code carefully? I changed `setTimeout = (changing,2000);` to `setTimeout(changing, 2000);`. You can tell it's different because my version works.